# How to update Django models from another app?

Tags: python, django

I have a running Django server using MySQL.I want **to modify its models from another python program.**

I came up with a few ideas.

1. Directly insert data into MySQL (will this reflect on model objects?)
2. Create a REST interface

I'm unfamiliar with Django's ORM, what is the right approach?

Comment: what do you mean by program, yes you can use `Rest framework` to create endpoints , then you can make changes using your client interface if you are unfamiliar with `Django ORM` i would suggest reading this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/ but still, i would recommend you stick with ORM as it generally makes easier to interact with DB and safe as well

Comment: Thank you for your advice. "Program" here refers to a python process, I'm trying to manipulate the same DB with two different python processes (Django server and my own script)  and I'm not sure whether it's safe to use Django ORM at this point.

Comment: I would suggest REST and you're going to use ORM anyway